# localsystem and NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account the same?

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a SQL Server job, and it needs a owner account. I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I entered "localsystem" then use Check Names function to let system automatically verifies the account I entered is correct.

After check name returns, the account becomes NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. My question is, whether account localsystem and NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM are the same? I am using Windows Server 2003 x64 Enterprise as the host OS.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Do you have any published documents to prove this? :-)

Comment: @george2: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322988 mentions it

Comment: Cool, question answered.